# Basic difference among PayPal payment methods

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

What is the difference among these paypal payment methods. I want to integrate with osCommerce.

PayPal Website Payments Pro (US) Direct Payments
PayPal Express Checkout
PayPal IPN
PayPal Website Payments Standard
PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK) Direct Payments
PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK) Express Checkout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PayPal Website Payments Pro (US) Direct Payments is an PayPal API-based solution that allows you to take card payments directly on your site. In addition, it has a $30 monthly fee and your account needs to be checked by PayPal. Lastly, you need to be PCI DSS compliant.

PayPal Express Checkout is an API-based solution that will doesn't necessarily require a buyer to enter any details on your site, allowing them a quick checkout through the PayPal site. (Although it's not required. You can still request an address on your cart if you so wish).
There is no monthly fee and everyone is free to use it.

PayPal IPN is Instant Payment Notification. In basic terms, PayPal will notify a script on your site via POST whenever a payment has gone through. Great for sending out customized 'Thank you' emails, updating your order database / stock levels, etc. I believe osCommerce only uses it for updating the order status. Oh, and it's free as well.

PayPal Website Payments Standard: forget about it. It's the same as Express Checkout, but worse and more insecure.

PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK) Direct Payments: An older version of Website Payments Pro that was available for some time in the UK. You'll know if you have this, otherwise forget about it.

PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK) Express Checkout: 100% the same as PayPal Express Checkout. Not sure why you have it available a second time.